# Transparent circles not showing up [HTML5/JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, shapes

I'm trying to draw fireflies on a canvas. I have a image of a 1x1 white pixel and I want to have a transparent circle surrounding it to simulate a glow. So far, I've managed to draw the circle, but when I try to change the global alpha of my 2d context, the image doesn't draw and neither does the circle. This has been confusing me for a while because I draw the image before I draw its surrounding circle. How can I go about fixing this?

My code:

```
thatBug.draw = function () {

    ctx.drawImage(bugImage, thatBug.x, thatBug.y, thatBug.size, thatBug.size);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalAlpha(0.4);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(thatBug.x, thatBug.y, thatBug.size + thatBug.glowAmt, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

};
```

Comment: You should always take a look in the console first to see if there are any errors. It would have told you that `ctx.globalAlpha is not a function` and [MDN: CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalAlpha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha) shows you that it is a property to set and not a function.

Comment: After posting this question along with an hour of struggling, I jumped and realized I hadn't even checked the console and it was probably because of an error. Guess I need to sleep more, thanks anyways @t.niese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself. ctx.globalAlpha(0.4) should be globalAlpha = 0.4